# why is clickhouse writing batch records slowly?

Tags: clickhouse

I use clickhouse-jdbc to write data to a distributed "all" table of clickhouse(3 hosts for 3 shards 1 replica).

5000 batch commit using PreparedStatement for 1000000 records costs 6280s.

```
...
                ps.setString(68, dateTimeStr);
                ps.setDate(69, date);
                
                ps.addBatch();
                System.out.println("i: " + i);
                
                if(i % 5000 == 0 || i == maxRecords) {
                    System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
                    ps.executeBatch();
                    System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
//                  ps.execute();
                    conn.commit();
                    System.out.println("commit: " + new java.util.Date());
                }
...
```

Is there any better way for inserting one hundred million records a day?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inserts into a [Distributed engine](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/distributed/) could be potentially slow due to the whole bunch of logic needed to be done on each insert operation (fsync the data to the specific shard, etc).

You can try to tune some settings, which are described in the link above.

However, I found it much convenient and faster to write into the underlying table directly. But it requires you to care about sharding and spreading the data across all of your nodes, ie distributing your data to your own taste.

Comment: Yes, writing into local table directly is more efficient.But we must consider the distribution and balance  of data

Comment: The distributed table will handle the distributed reads anyway by issuing read select to all local tables. It's good (you can potentially get benefits during the reads) to get the data of the same "sharding" key as close to each other as possible. Though with simple round-robin data distribution it will just mean all of your shards will carry a "fraction" so all of them will do some work on extracting it during the read query time. I think it depends on the data and how you see it should be structured. This is a trade-off.